# Get return type of template method in a template class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, invoke-result

I have a following not compiling code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct bar {

  template <typename... Args>
  auto func(Args... args)
  {
    return foo(*this, args...);
  }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using bar_func_return_type = std::invoke_result_t<&bar<T>::func, Args...>; // ERROR HERE

int main()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<bar_func_return_type<int, float, double>, foo<int, floar, double>)
  {
    std::cout << "OK";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "FAIL";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get the result type of `bar::func` method.
I get an error `Template argument for template type parameter must be a type` when specifying `bar_func_return_type`. How can I get the desired return type?

Comment: `foo` is a (empty) type, `foo(*this, args...)` is wrong...

Comment: `std::invoke_result_t<&bar<T>::func, Args...>` should be `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&bar<T>::func<Args...>), bar<T>, Args...>`.

Comment: @Jarod42, it didn't work https://godbolt.org/z/9T5rMWYM6

Comment: Missing `template` because of dependent name, and once issues/typo fixed, it works [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/vbrc9d9sK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like their are a lot of details missing from your code.
I tried to `fix` them and get something that actually wants to compile.

Key ingredient to get return type =
`template <typename T, typename... Args> using bar_func_return_type = decltype(std::declval<bar<T>>().func(std::declval<Args>()...));`

Full code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct foo 
{
    // foo missed a constructor with correct types
    foo(const T&, Args&&...)
    {
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct bar 
{
    // Args&& is a bit more flexible in practice
    template <typename... Args>
    auto func(Args&&... args)
    {
        return foo<bar,Args...>(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

// std::declval makes default instances ot the types specified
// this is usually how I deduce return values (could be invoke_result_t is actually a bit more easy to use.
template <typename T, typename... Args>
using bar_func_return_type = decltype(std::declval<bar<T>>().func(std::declval<Args>()...));

int main()
{
    using retval_t = bar_func_return_type<int, float, double>;

    // No need to do a runtime check, you can already
    // test at compile time using static_assert
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<retval_t, foo<bar<int>, float, double>>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly `foo<bar, std::decay_t<Args>...>` or remove `<..>` completely and let CTAD decide.